# If $x = \operatorname{argmin}_{x \in X} \lvert Ax - y\rvert^2$ does it mean that $Ax = \operatorname{Proj}_X(Ay)$?

Tags: real-analysis, optimization, elementary-functions

Suppose that $A$ is an invertible matrix and

$$x = \operatorname{argmin}_{x \in X}\lvert Ax - y\rvert^2,$$

then does it mean that $Ax  = \operatorname{Proj}_X(y)$ like in the definition of projection? I mean, the definition gives that it would be the case if

$$Ax = \operatorname{argmin}_{Ax \in X}\lvert Ax - y\rvert^2.$$

But does the above relation imply this one?

Comment: Context is missing: what stops me from taking $x=y$?

Comment: Oops. My mistake. I mean $Ax - y$. Fixed now.

Comment: is $X$ a vector space?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, this is definitely not correct. The solution is in fact
$$x=A^{-1}\textrm{Proj}_{Y}(y)$$
where $Y=AX$; that is, $Y$ is the set
$$Y\triangleq AX = \{ Ax \,|\, x\in X\} = \{ y \,|\, A^{-1}y\in X \}.$$
Whether or not an efficient projection can be constructed in this case, or whether that projection can utilize an existing $\textrm{Proj}_X$ implementation, will depend on the specific structure of $X$.